Persist scroll position between pages in Blazor MAUI Hybrid
Is there anyway to keep the scrolling position while navigating between Razor pages in Blazor MAUI Hybrid? We have Page A with a master-detail system. When user scroll downs in Page A (could be way down the page), then clicks an item go to Page B for details, then when navigating back the user scroll position is on the top of the page again which is quite annoying and unexpected. We have been trying to resolve this by saving the state and with javascript use scrollTo in order to restore the position but it doesn't work well because its flickering when trying to restore the position, especially if its far down. We read that there should be something about this in Blazor Enhanced Navigation but can't understand how it works or how we can enable that. We are using .NET 8.

Is this an SPA? If so, then there won't be any top-level navigation events that would cause the viewport's scroll to reset on-load - it's possible you have a #fragment-identifier that's causing the viewport to jump to an element that's only coincidentally at the top of the page.

I guess this would not be classified as a SPA because we are using the @page concept of Blazor, you mean the only way to keep the scroll state would be to wrap everything into one Page? Seems doable to put everything as components into one page but very unpractical coding wise. The URL does change between master-detail navigation I guess thats why it keeps scrolling to the top.

Probably related to this issue, Blazor NavigationManager.NavigateTo always scrolls page to the top.
